# Google Drive credential returns 403 insufficientPermissions

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to get a list of files' data from Drive.
Following the google's example didn't work.

This is an example of my code:

```
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

private Drive createDriveService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
    {
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        InputStream in = ImageImpl.class.getResourceAsStream(USER_CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        return new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(applicationName)
                .build();
    }

    public void listFiles() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
    {
        Drive service = createDriveService();
        FileList result = service.files().list()
                .setPageSize(10)
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                .execute();
        List<File> files = result.getFiles();
    }
```

Output:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=nextPageToken,%20files(id,%20name)&pageSize=10
{
  "code": 403,
  "details": [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
      "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
      "domain": "googleapis.com",
      "metadata": {
        "service": "drive.googleapis.com",
        "method": "google.apps.drive.v3.DriveFiles.List"
      }
    }
  ],
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Insufficient Permission",
      "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Any ideas?

I've tried test the Query here -> https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/list and works ok, but not locally
Also, I'm using the same credential to have access to a Sheet by ID and works, so that tells me the authentication it's fine, the only difference is the scope.

Answer (score 0):

go to TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH And delete the file there.

You previously authorized your application then changed the scope.

Your app needs to request authorization of the user again and request the new scope.

Comment: Sorry, still the same

Comment: Did it pop up and request authorization again?

Comment: Fixed, I just need to add both scopes to the credential. As the app get info from Sheets and then from Drive. I was creating 2 different credentials with different scopes. But I've realized after @DalmTo comment the token it will be generated only with the Sheets scope :/ So, the solution is add both scopes to the credential the first time so the token have the correct privileges. Thanks :)